# How can I make this dictionary look better?

Tags: overleaf

So I am working on a conlang (constructed language) and am trying to start write it's dictionary. I have the following setup

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,margin=0.75in,paperwidth=5.25in,paperheight=8in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\leftmark}
% set the font
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{bch}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
% remove chapter numbering
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code
% remove section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% this is how we define the actual dictionary items. markboth is for 
% setting the page headers so that first and last words appear there.
\newcommand{\ditem}[1]{\item[#1] \markboth{\footnotesize \textbf{#1}}{\footnotesize \textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% title page
\begin{center}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vbox{\vspace{5cm}
{\huge Birāznékhteria Dictionary}}
\vfill
{\large Trinity}
\vfill

\end{center}
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Preface
\chapter{Preface}

This is the preface.

\newpage

% \chapter{The Dictionary}
% we'd like the text size to be a bit smaller for the definitions
\footnotesize
% we'd like two columns of definitions

% Section A start
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{description}
\section{A}
\ditem{Abandon} \textit{-v.} definition 1 \textit{-n.} definition 2
\ditem{Abandoned} \textit{-v.} definition 1 \textit{-n.} definition 2

\end{description}
\end{multicols}
 % Section A Ends
 
 % Section S starts
 \begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{description}
\section{S}
\ditem{Sarpa} \textbf{sar.pa} \textit{n.} Snake, A long reptilian with no legs which lives on water and land. (Colloquially) A person who act nice to you but is a foe.
\ditem{Sugor} \textbf{su.gor} \textit{n.} Tree
\end{description}
\end{multicols}
 % Section s Ends
 
\end{document}
```

The thing is at rendering it doesn't look good and some of the text is misplaced (idk if there's a flaw in the code) which is like this.

[image]

so my question is how can I make it better and look better?

Specifically I want to know how to make the definition text in same block

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's more traditional to continue the alphabetic listing in the same column, rather than balancing the columns for one letter before the end of a page.  If you prefer to arrange the dictionary the way you show in your example, it would be good to insert some sort of visible separator at a letter break to help the reader.  Some possibilities are shown in these TUGboat articles: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84peter.pdf or https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Look this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,emptypage} 
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,margin=0.75in,paperwidth=5.25in,paperheight=8in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\leftmark}
% set the font
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{bch}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
% remove chapter numbering
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code
% remove section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% this is how we define the actual dictionary items. markboth is for 
% setting the page headers so that first and last words appear there.
\newcommand{\ditem}[1]{\item[#1] \markboth{\footnotesize \textbf{#1}}{\footnotesize \textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% title page
\begin{center}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vbox{\vspace{5cm}
{\huge Birāznékhteria Dictionary}}
\vfill
{\large Trinity}
\vfill

\end{center}
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Preface
\chapter{Preface}

This is the preface.

\newpage

% \chapter{The Dictionary}
% we'd like the text size to be a bit smaller for the definitions
\footnotesize
% we'd like two columns of definitions
\section{A}
% Section A start
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{description}

\ditem{Abandon} \textit{-v.} definition 1 \textit{-n.} definition 2
\ditem{Abandoned} \textit{-v.} left \textit{-n.} definition 2
\ditem{Alone} \textbf{a.lo.ne} \textit{-n.} only one person 
\ditem{Atom} \textit{-n.} definition 1 \textit{-n.} 

\end{description}
\end{multicols}
 % Section A Ends
\section{S} 
 % Section S starts
 \begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{description}

\ditem{Sarpa} \textbf{sar.pa} \textit{n.} Snake, A long reptilian with no legs which lives on water and land. (Colloquially) A person who act nice to you but is a foe.
\ditem{Sugor} \textbf{su.gor} \textit{n.} Tree
\ditem{Sigaro} \textbf{si.ga.ro} \textit{n.} Big sigarette
\end{description}
\end{multicols}
 % Section s Ends
 
\end{document}
```

And his principal output (some improvements also for empy pages):

[image]